# setting wdullaer/MaterialTimePicker Time limit values in not working

Tags: android, timepicker, android-timepicker

I'm using `https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker` in order to use their `TimePickerDialog` but it seems that the `setMin/MaxTime` is not working even though they wrote about it in the documentation

```
 val picker = TimePickerDialog(
            context,
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { view, hourOfDay, minute -> },
            hourOfDay,
            minOfDay,
            false
        )

        picker.setMaxTime(...)
        picker.show()
```

as expected from the documentation the time picker has a `setMin/MaxTime()` methods but when using it in the project none exists!

Answer (score 0):

Use this format:

```
picker.setMaxTime(Timepoint(hour, minute, second))
```